# iPhone - Prevent tick sound at the end of a played sound with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, audio, avaudioplayer

At the end of a short sound played with an AVAudioPlayer, I hear a "tick" sound.  I'm playing a repeatedly timed very short sound (0.1 sec) and that "tick" at the end of each play is very very disturbing. How may I prevent that "tick" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the beginning and end of your sound file contains at least a few milliseconds of silence.

The AVAudioPlayer may still produce a tick on some devices with some OS versions, even after 100 mS of silence.  If so, you may have to use another audio API.  Mixing sound effects into a continuously running Audio Queue or the RemoteIO Audio Unit may be the only way to guarantee absolutely no clicks on all iOS device & OS version combinations.

Comment: Even if a different API is used, wouldn't it ultimately have to use AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: @Ravi - It's the other way around.  AVAudioPlayer runs on top of some Audio Units.

Comment: Do you have some great reference to "Audio Queue or the RemoteIO Audio Unit" ? I've read tons of pages on the Apple Doc about audio processing, and the only one I've really understood was the AVAudioPlayer. All the other one are very obscure for me.